# Zip creation file stops at about 25MB with PHP shared hosting

Tags: php, zip, hosting, limit, filesize

I have a shared hosting account.

Some of my PHP creates a ZIP file. Generally, this works without issue. However, for the last 2 days, whenever the file robe zipped gets larger than about 25MB the script stops abruptly. The ZIP file can be downloaded, but is corrupt.

Note that ZIP files under 25MB are not corrupt.

2 days ago, I found this error in the error log:

> [02-May-2015 23:04:57 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  Unknown: write
>   failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0
>
> [02-May-2015 23:04:57 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed
>   to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting
>   of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0

This seems to indicate that there is not enough space left on the hosting side. I bought the hosting package because they advertised with unlimited space.

Part of the issue may be that the host has ulimit (System-Command) set to allow no more than 25MB of virtual memory per process.

Am I right? Can I fix this issue myself? Would support understand when contacted about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that the shared host has run out of space on the machine your website is hosted on. Contact them and they should be able to fix it. Easy peasy.

Comment: yeah I figured, they fixed it already and probably by setting ulimit to 25MB. Which hurts my script. How can I fix that?

Comment: Contact your host about this. 25MB per process seems awfully low. Also, don't forget to accept if this answer was helpful.

Comment: @user1557314 what do you mean by "fix?" If they set the ulimit to 25mb, you can't make zips larger than 25mb.